# Updating a stacked bar chart in d3.js (includes JSFiddle)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

jsfiddle example can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clery00/9KLJU/)

I'm expecting the chart to update correctly with the new dataset contained in the function "redraw", however this isn't happening.

Although the current rects are updated with the new dataset, the issue seems to be that the enter().append() part of the code isn't working:

```
var groups = svg.selectAll('g')
  .data(dataset, retd);

groups.style('fill', function (d, i) {
      return colours(i);
});

groups.enter()
  .append('g')
  .style('fill', function (d, i) {
      return colours(i);
});

groups.exit().remove();

//update the Rects
var rects = groups.selectAll('rect')
            .data(function (d) {
               return d;
            }, thisy);

rects.transition()
  .attr('x', function (d) {
      return xScale(d.x0);
  })
  .attr('y', function (d, i) {
      return yScale(d.y);
  })
  .attr('height', function (d) {
      return yScale.rangeBand();
  })
  .attr('width', function (d) {
      return xScale(d.x);
  });

rects.enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function (d) {
        return xScale(d.x0);
    })
    .attr('y', function (d, i) {
        return yScale(d.y);
    })
    .attr('height', function (d) {
        return yScale.rangeBand();
    })
    .attr('width', function (d) {
        return xScale(d.x);
    });
```

Any help/insight would be appreciated.

Comment: In the JSFiddle, where does the `redraw` function get declared?

Comment: The fiddle was incorrect. It should be fixed now, sorry about that.

Comment: What do you expect to happen that's not happening?

Comment: I'm expecting it to update correctly with the new dataset. Note the dataset within the function "redraw" has a number of different "IS" values versus the dataset used before the "redraw" function is executed.

Comment: In the fiddle, regarding "IS", are you wanting to make sure each "IS" is an integer? That loop with: `d.IS = +d.IS;` is not hitting "IS".

Comment: You are correct, I have removed the offending piece of code. Line 33 to 42 correctly ensures IS is an integer in this case.

Comment: Does the initial draw do what you expect? Are you expecting to the redraw to be similar to the first draw, but having different values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the first draw worked fine, I turned it into a function. Only had to remove the already written SVG to make it reusable:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/Yp7PL/)

```
<button id="reset">Redraw</button>

<script>

document.getElementById('reset').onclick = function() {
    var dataset = [
        {"data":[
            {"IssueMonth":"Apr","IS":"350","month":"Apr"},
            {"IssueMonth":null,"IS":"100","month":"Aug"},
            {"IssueMonth":null,"IS":"0","month":"Dec"}],
         "name":"CHF"},
        {"data":[
            {"IssueMonth":null,"IS":"100","month":"Apr"},
            {"IssueMonth":null,"IS":"200","month":"Aug"},
            {"IssueMonth":null,"IS":"40","month":"Dec"}],
         "name":"GBP"}
    ];
    drawit(dataset);
}

var dataset = [
    {"data":[
        {"IssueMonth":"Apr","IS":"350","month":"Apr"},
        {"IssueMonth":null,"IS":"0","month":"Aug"},
        {"IssueMonth":null,"IS":"0","month":"Dec"}],
     "name":"CHF"},
    {"data":[
        {"IssueMonth":null,"IS":"100","month":"Apr"},
        {"IssueMonth":null,"IS":"0","month":"Aug"},
        {"IssueMonth":null,"IS":"50","month":"Dec"}],
     "name":"GBP"}
];

drawit(dataset);

function drawit(dataset) {

    var margins = {
        top: 40,
        left: 40,
        right: 40,
        bottom: 40
    };

    var width = 400;
    var height = 500 - margins.top - margins.bottom;

    var series = dataset.map(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    });

    var dataset = dataset.map(function (d) {
        return d.data.map(function (o, i) {
            // Structure it so that your numeric
            // axis (the stacked amount) is y
            return {
                y: +o.IS,
                x: o.month
            };
        });
    });

    stack = d3.layout.stack();

    stack(dataset);

    var dataset = dataset.map(function (group) {
        return group.map(function (d) {
            // Invert the x and y values, and y0 becomes x0
            return {
                x: d.y,
                y: d.x,
                x0: d.y0
            };
        });
    });

    d3.select("svg").remove();    
    var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margins.left + margins.right)
    .attr('height', height + margins.top + margins.bottom)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')')

    var xMax = d3.max(dataset, function (group) {
        return d3.max(group, function (d) {
            return d.x + d.x0;
        });
    })

    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, xMax])
    .range([0, width]);

    var months = dataset[0].map(function (d) {
        return d.y;
    });

    var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(months)
    .rangeRoundBands([0, height], .1);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient('bottom');

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient('left');

    var colours = d3.scale.category20();

    var groups = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .style('fill', function (d, i) {
        return colours(i);
    });

    var rects = groups.selectAll('rect')
    .data(function (d) {
        return d;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function (d) {
        return xScale(d.x0);
    })
    .attr('y', function (d, i) {
        return yScale(d.y);
    })
    .attr('height', function (d) {
        return yScale.rangeBand();
    })
    .attr('width', function (d) {
        return xScale(d.x);
    });

    svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis);

    svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(yAxis);
}

</script>
```